# How to get HTML translate attribute work with angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am trying to add the "translate" attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/translate) to my HTML elements in my angularjs (v1) app which also has angular-translate. My goal is to prevent Chrome translate the app pages. As far as I can see, the angular-translate defines a "translate" directive which prevents the HTML translate attribute work.

Are there any solutions to this other than hacking the angular-translate "translate" directive?